# Disable parent in wp_list_pages - Wordpress

Tags: menus, pages, sitemap

I have the following code the generates the sitemap.

```
 wp_list_pages(
                                array(
                                    'exclude' => '5',
                                    'sort_column' => 'ID',
                                    'title_li' => ''
                                )
                            );
```

It generates a hierarchy of my Pages but it also has links to my parent pages.

[image]

check the screenshot above. I only need the title for all the parents not the link.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: why not creating your own function as this one is a default WP one and it behave like this

Comment: Can you please provide any example code for this? I am new to Wordpress.

Comment: You have at least five choices: 1) extend `Walker_Page` to use within `wp_list_pages()` ; 2) create a navigation menu; 3) write your own function; 4) filter out `<a>` tag from the return of `wp_list_pages()` using regular expression; 5) use CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_pages()` instead and write some custom code like this :

```
$args = array('exclude' => '5',
             'sort_column' => 'ID'
       )
$pages = get_pages($args); 
  foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    echo $page->post_title;
  }
```

You may of course elaborate more the code in order to obtain a tree.

You may also check the source code of `wp_list_pages()` and you will see that there is the `get_pages()` function, so you may also copy its code and modify it :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/#source